# Shallenberger Acree example

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

At the moment I'm writing a paper about sweeteners and want to compare saccharides, polyoles and synthetic sweeteners like cyclamate.

I'm having some problems trying to apply the Shallenberger–Acree model and would like an explanation for Glucose/Sucrose and Maltitol since I already figured it out for Cyclamate.

Please keep your English simple since it isn't my native language.